# Optimize MySQL Query using explain

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql-5.6

I have following SQL

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.evnumber=B.evnumber
INNER JOIN D ON B.userid=D.userid

This is explain result.

```
[
{
    "id": "1",
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "A",
    "type": "index",
    "possible_keys": "evnumber",
    "key": "evnumber",
    "key_len": "768",
    "ref": null,
    "rows": "13926",
    "Extra": "Using where; Using index"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "B",
    "type": "ref",
    "possible_keys": "evnumber,UserID",
    "key": "evnumber",
    "key_len": "768",
    "ref": "A.evnumber",
    "rows": "1",
    "Extra": "Using where"
},
{
    "id": "1",
    "select_type": "SIMPLE",
    "table": "D",
    "type": "ref",
    "possible_keys": "mdl_userinfodata_usefie_ix",
    "key": "mdl_userinfodata_usefie_ix",
    "key_len": "8",
    "ref": "B.UserId",
    "rows": "134",
    "Extra": "Using where; Using index"
}
```

]

When I execute this SQL, it takes 40 seconds.
According to products of values of rows column (13926x134x1=1,866,084), it is impossible, I think.
Please help me, How can I improve this?
MySQL version is 5.6

Comment: Provide complete DDLs for all tables.

Comment: Thank you for posting the EXPLAIN in a format that is easy to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query is already using indexes for the joins, but it isn't using a covering index for B. That's the only possible improvement I can see.

I would add a compound index on B for columns `(evnumber, user_id)`. That should allow the query get "Using index" for table B, indicating that it uses the index only, it doesn't have to read table rows. It won't reduce the number you see in `rows: 1` for table B, but it will help make it a little easier for B to join to D.

Sometimes this type of optimization has given a good result. For very large tables, it can improve performance a lot. But your tables are small, so it may not make as great a difference.

Comment: Thank you @Karwin, table D has 928,430 records and table A has 12990 records. And B has 82665. I think this is not small. I will try to add compound index as you said.